# Split an underscore-delimited string, but ignore underscores occurring in a url

Tags: php, regex, split, text-parsing, delimited

Below string I need to split. I tried with the `explode()`, but it is fragmenting the url substring.

```
$link = "7_5_7_http://test.com/folder/images/7_newim/5_car/7_february2013/p/a00/p01/video-1.mov_00:00:09";

$ex_link = explode('_',$link);
```

It is splitting the string after every "_' symbol, but I need to the results like this:

```
$ex_link[0] = '7';
$ex_link[1] = '5';
$ex_link[2] = '7';
$ex_link[3] = 'http://test.com/folder/images/7_newim/5_car/7_february2013/p/a00/p01/video-1.mov';
$ex_link[2] = '00:00:09';
```

Comment: Take a look at [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and http://www.regular-expressions.info/ to get started.

Comment: For a task that involves strings with unknown string variability, we cannot recommend a "best" solution by only knowing one sample string.  There are too many ways that this task can be achieved "correctly", but many of these solutions may only be suitable for the single presented string.  Needs More Clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) has a third parameter, <strike>why do people complicate things ?</strike>

```
$link = "7_5_7_http://test.com/folder/images/7_newim/5_car/7_february2013/p/a00/p01/video-1.mov_00:00:09";
$array = explode('_', $link, 4);
$temp = array_pop($array);
$array = array_merge($array, array_reverse(array_map('strrev', explode('_', strrev($temp), 2)))); // Now it has just become complexer (facepalm)
print_r($array);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 7
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 7
    [3] => http://test.com/folder/images/7_newim/5_car/7_february2013/p/a00/p01/video-1.mov
    [4] => 00:00:09
)
```

**[Online demo](http://viper-7.com/lGnrgA)**

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
preg_match('/(\d)_(\d)_(\d)_([\w:\.\/\/\-]+)_([\d]{2}:[\d]{2}:[\d]{2})/', $link, $matches);
```

And $matches:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(95) "7_5_7_http://test.com/folder/images/7_newim/5_car/7_february2013/p/a00/p01/video-1.mov_00:00:09"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "7"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "7"
  [4]=>
  string(80) "http://test.com/folder/images/7_newim/5_car/7_february2013/p/a00/p01/video-1.mov"
  [5]=>
  string(8) "00:00:09"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This one is simplest one

```
$result = preg_split('%_(?=(\d|http://))%si', $subject);
```

Comment: The `s` pattern modifier is useless here because there are no dots in the pattern.  This answer is missing its educational explanation.